# How do you let ssh timeout quickly?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm working on a setup where I often lose connection with the ssh server that I'm connected to.  Normally when this happens my ssh client takes several **minutes** before it times out with:
`client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`

I'd like to lower this timeout to a few seconds.  How can I achieve this?  I've tried

```
ConnectTimeout=1
ConnectionAttempts=3
```

but this doesn't achieve my desired goal of a quick timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the option you're looking for is `ServerAliveInterval`, as documented in `man 5 ssh_config`.